# Word services - how to use?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, office-365

I have question - how can I use  Word services?

And how I can use Word automatically converse to PDF file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Word Automation Service is not available in Office 365/SharePoint online.

Have a look here:
http://www.spdavid.com/post/2010/11/12/Office-365-Service-Descriptions-SharePoint-Online-vs-Standard.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need enable Word Automation Services through Manage Service Applications in the Central Administration. Once the service application is started you just need to enable a few settings as mentioned [here](http://mysharepointadventures.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/enable-the-document-conversion-service/) . This should get you started comfortably without much problems.

Answer (score 0):

Many resources are about Work Automation Services:

- [Developing with SharePoint 2010 Word Automation Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742315.aspx)
- [Word Automation Services: How it Works](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2010/01/18/word-automation-services-_2d00_-how-it-works.aspx)
- [Introducing Word Automation Services](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2009/10/26/introducing-word-automation-services.aspx)
- [Using SharePoint 2010 Word Automation Services to convert Word
  documents to PDF files](http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2011/05/01/using-sharepoint-2010-word-automation-services-to-convert-word-documents-files-to-pdf-files.aspx)